# Could not load file or assembly 'Assembly.dll' - vstest

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dll, visual-studio-2013, filenotfoundexception

I have such error when launching one unit test:
Test method TestName threw exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Assembly.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be
found.

This issue occurs only when using vstest.console.exe. It doesn't occur when I run my test through Visual Studio (2013). I know that vstest.executionengine.exe is run when running tests through Visual Studio. Logs for it can be enabled in vstest.executionengine.exe.config file (but it doesn't give me any useful information).

I already used Dependency Walker as suggested in many other questions of these type:
[image: Dependency Walker screenshot]
And I see that I have all dlls colored to red in System32 directory or in the program execution directory (Dependency walker thinks that they are missing). Execution of tests looks like this:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "dll1.dll" "dll2.dll" (etc. for all dlls with tests) /InIsolation /UseVsixExtensions:false /Platform:x86 /Framework:framework40 /Logger:trx /Tests:TestName
(and all possible missing dlls, only not API-MS-WIN(...) named dlls are in TestWindow or System32 directory).
I have already checked.
I have Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2008, 2010, 2012 and 2013 installed in both x86 and x64 versions.
Name of missing dll and name of test were changed, of course they have another names :)

Comment: Have you tried [assembly binding logging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/e74a18c4)? Verify that `vstest.console.exe` is starting from the same location and using the same `PATH` in its environment. You can capture the command line/environment of the successful `vstest.executionengine.exe` using Process Explorer.

Comment: Sorry I replied so late. It was as you thought Jeroen Mostert :) The PATH variable was another for 2 environments I used. One directory wasn't in the PATH and because of that DLL could not be found. I found out about this on Thursday but I didn't post the answer at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation:
The PATH variable was another for 2 environments I used. One directory wasn't in the PATH environment variable and because of that DLL could not be found. Adding this key directory to PATH variable solved the problem. The environment with incomplete PATH variable was Jenkins.